# "invalid `method'" error when I try the step.Gam function

Tags: r, distance, sampling, gam

I have a `gam` function with many covariates and I would like to simplify it (find the minimum model)

I used a `dsm` function to model the density of a species across line transcect segments as a function of covariates. And it works fine! 
But it was the maximum model with too many covariates and I would like to reduce their number automatically. So I tried using the `gam::step.Gam` function. (I also used the `gam.scope` function to make sure I do everything correctly).

DSM code:

```
GamModel = dsm(
  ddf.obj=PreparedDdf, 
  formula = D ~ x + y + Cov1 + Cov2 +...+ Covn factor1+ factor2+...+factorn,
  family=gaussian(link='identity'), 
  group=FALSE,
  engine='gam',
  convert.units=1,
  segment.data=segment.df, 
  observation.data=observation.df
)
```

step.Gam code:

```
GamScope=gam.scope(segment.df[,c(5:6,11:16)], response=1, smoother="s", arg=NULL, form=TRUE)
MinModel = step.Gam(GamModel, GamScope, trace=TRUE, direction="backward")
```

I hoped to get the minimal model, instead it gives me the following error:

> Error in gam(formula = D ~ x + Cov1 + Cov2 + Cov3,  :  invalid `method': REML

And I don't understand why this happens! I tried different  methods (GACV.Cp, ML) and I get the same kind of error (invalid method: GACV.Cp etc)
Why is this happening? Is it because it's gam model produced by the dsm function?
And more importantly, how can I minimize the model automatically??

(When I used `engine='glm'` instead of `'gam'` in the `dsm` function) and I try the `stats::step` function to find the minimal model it works, but the results seem a bit scetcy... so I want to use the gam engine)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? It will help us to help you out.

Comment: I just logged in to do so (you are right, I should have done that straight away) to find out someone explained the problem below. Many thanks for your help anyway!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **gam** package doesn't fit models using REML or the other options you state. Those are options to the `gam()` function in the **mgcv** package.

The only allowed options for the `method` argument in `gam::gam()` are:

1. `"glm.fit"`, which is the default, and
2. `"model.frame"`, which doesn't really do anything as it instructs the function to just spit out the model frame resulting from the formula.

It is quite important to differentiate between these two packages that both provide a `gam()` function. They are very different approaches to the estimation of GAMs.

As you are using `dsm()`, you'll be fitting using `mgcv::gam()` not `gam::gam()` and in that case you cannot apply the `gam::step.gam()` function to the model.

I believe that the authors of `dsm()` recommend that you use the `select = TRUE` argument to `mgcv::gam()`, which you can provide when using `dsm()` and which will get passed on the `gam()`. This will add extra penalties to the smooth terms in the model such that they can be shrunk out of the model.

Comment: Aaah this explains everything!! Thank you so much!! Could you also tell me: when I use select=TRUE, I noticed that the covariates that get the penalties are not automatically removed from the model. Can I take them all out in one ago, or should I do it step by step? Or is it fine if I leave them there, since their effect gets minimized? (I hope I understood that correctly...)

Comment: You don't want to remove them, the shrinkage from the penalties will decide how much a term should contribute to the model. If a term uses much less than 1 EDF then it is essentially removed from the model, but if you then actually remove it from the model you are making a very strong statement that the effect is exactly **zero**. Leaving the terms in the model accepts that the effect may not be exactly zero, but you account for not knowing this beforehand in all the statistical outputs from the model (well, those that come from `mgcv::gam()`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!! Do you know how small is a "much less than 1 EDF" though? Is 0.0004 small enough? I don't want to overdo it...

Comment: Well, any shrinkage below 1 EDF means the term has had it's null space (the linear bit of the basis, loosely speaking) shrunk as well as the wiggly part. If we think of a linear term in a model as using 1 DF, anything less than 1EDF suggests that term is contributing less than a standard linear term. If the EDF is <0.1 then it really is contributing little, and if <0.0001 it is effectively shrunk out of the model.